# Unable to upload logstash information to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to output my logstash information from my virtual machine to my window's elasticsearch.

However i am unable to do so. It kept giving me the error, 'Failed to install template: Connection refused (Connection refused) {:level=>:error}

Below is the code configuration i have set on my linux logstash.conf file.

```
input{
        file{
            path => ['tmp/testing/testing.log']
            start_position =>beginning
        }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:class}\-%{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
    #overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
}
output{
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => ['localhost:9200']
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your ES instance is up? what do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200` ?

Comment: Hi, my ES instance is up. I am running my ES on my window and my logstash on my linux(virtual machine)

Comment: Well, the error indicates that Logstash cannot reach it. Are you sure it runs on port 9200?

Comment: Yes. I did a http://localhost:9200/ on my windows and it is running fine.

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` and show the output you get?

Comment: It shows me an error, "failed to install template: connection refused (Connection refused) {:level=>error, file =>logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb", :line=>"270", :method=>"register"}

Comment: I would like to see the whole log please.

Comment: sorry but how can i show you the entire log ? I mean is there a way to generate the debug log file ?

Comment: As I said above, you need to run logstash with the `--debug` switch

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the configuration on my elasticsearch.yml, network.host to 0.0.0.0. After which, copy the publish_address that was displayed on your elasticsearch cmd and use that number in your linux logstash.